# mobile screen height disable div contract with text editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

You know when you have a div 100vh and you are in a mobile phone and you click a textbox and the editor comes up, well the problem is that the div contracts when the editor pops up is there a css command to stop the div contracting up, I tried min-height and the div still contracts up in size. I need something like min-height but it doesn't work

Comment: I also tried adding height of a fixed number but the div still compacts ups and the background-image gets changed anyway to prevent this

Comment: Please share a working codepen/jsfiddle.